# Im getting the error got "map", expected "string" on kubernetes service yaml

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I´m getting the error

> got "map", expected "string",

when I try to apply a service.yaml via..

> kubectl apply -f service.yaml

Here is my service.yaml

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gettime
  labels:
    app: jexxa
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jexxa
    type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
    - port: 7000
      targetPort: 7000
```

and here the whole error message :

> error: error validating "service.yaml": error validating data: >io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServiceSpec.selector: got "map", expected "string", >ValidationError(Service.spec.selector.ports): invalid type for >io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServiceSpec.selector: got "array", expected "string"]; if you choose to ignore >these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

I also tried it with `--validate=false` but it didnt work..

Comment: `type:` and `ports:` are indented one step too many; they should be under `spec:`, not `selector:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below should work. Removed `matchLabels`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gettime
  labels:
    app: jexxa
spec:
  selector:
    app: jexxa
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 7000
      targetPort: 7000
```